# How can I include all the calendars from my phone?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eventkit

I made an app which fetches all the calendar events through `EventKit` but the code I wrote works only on particular title:

```
func readEvents() {


    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
    for calendar in calendars {
       if calendar.title == "Work"{
            //let predicate = eventStore.predicateForReminders(in: [calendar])
            let oneMonthAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*3600)
            let oneMonthAfter = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: +30*24*3600)
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneMonthAgo as Date, end: oneMonthAfter as Date, calendars: [calendar])

            var events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
            for event in events {

                titles.append(event.title)
                print([titles])
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This only works for events which are in "work" calendar, how can I include all the events irrespective of the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this part?

```
if calendar.title == "Work"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all your calendars in the `calendars` array. In the iteration you iterate through all but have a condition to only get additional information if the calendar is called **Work**. Remove the `if-statement` and you´ll get information for all the calendars.

Answer (score 0):

Will these options enable you to select which calendar you want to add the event to, or does this add to all calendars?